# How to find and click element in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

`<input type="submit" value="Example" id="free_button_form_button" class="free_swag_element new_button_style profile_page_button_style">`

I'm trying to have selenium click the button but that is all the website uses and I don't know how to make it click.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "http://websitethatyouwanttoscrape.com"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

button = driver.find_element_by_id('free_button_form_button')
button.click()
```

Or if you need to wait until the button is clickable, you can:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver

url = "http://websitethatyouwanttoscrape.com"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'free_button_form_button')))
ActionChains(driver).click(button).perform()
```

Comment: Right. I already tried the first one, and the second one will not work because the button is always clickable when clicking manually but selenium wont work for some reason.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. Have you tried accessing it by CSS selector or by xpath? I've had problems using Selenium in the past by using IDs, but I have been able to use it by other methods. Wish I could help.

Comment: I have tried using xpath and css selector both of which fail to work.